# how to enable translation module for panel title in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal

I have panel module installed and enable in my site which is built in drupal 6.26 and the version of my panel module is 6.x-3.10. I have created many blocks with the panel and I am having two languages in my site : English and French.

I have also installed and enabled Translation module. Its working fine for other things but not for the title of the panel.

I have searched a lot for this on net but not getting proper solution yet.

thanks in advance.!

Comment: translation is handled by the t() function in drupal. You will need to share more information for us to be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you require any sort of i18n or l10n (internationalization/localization) for Drupal, you should review this doc:

http://drupal-translation.com/

Answering your question, this is taken directly from drupal-translation:

reference: http://drupal-translation.com/content/translating-block-contents#

> Drupal's i18n module can translate block contents.
>
> To display blocks in multiple languages, you can use one of these
>   approaches:
>
> Creating a different block for each language. Using string
>   localization When you create a block, you can choose to assign it to a
>   specific language or to all languages and use string translation.
>
> Method 1 - different blocks per language Select a unique language for
>   the block and indicate which nodes to display it for. You should
>   select only nodes that are written in the same language as the block.
>
> Then, create similar blocks in other languages and enable them for the
>   nodes in those languages.
>
> This process will keep complete isolation between blocks in different
>   languages. They can be translations of each other, but can also
>   contain completely independent contents. Drupal and i18n don't offer
>   any facilities for synchronizing between block contents in different
>   languages.
>
> Method 2 - string localization Drupal can translate strings from
>   English to other languages (currently, there is no solution for
>   translating from any language other than English). You can tell Drupal
>   to handle the title and contents of blocks as strings and look for
>   translations using Drupal's string translation mechanism.
>
> When a block is being displayed in a different language, Drupal will
>   look up the title and body of the block to see if there is a string
>   translation of the title and body. If they are available the
>   translation will be displayed otherwise it will display the original
>   text.

Answer (score 0):

In D7 I have used the following workaround :

1. In panels, I have added to the to the footer a translated standard node without any content (e.g. Basic page). You can also add it to any other region not impacting your layout.
2. For panel title I have selected the title option "*From pane*".
3. On my translated node I flagged the option "*Panel title*".  This option it will appear only after your set your panel title to "*From pane*".
4. On the pane options for this node, I have overridden the title to blank.
5. Final result - the panel title is inherited from the title of the translated node, which itself is not visible.

Hope this will work for you in Drupal 6. For menu item translations, in case you will need it, I have manually added the multilingual menu links pointing to the same panel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).